# Proof Verification: Limit of Integral and Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

**Q)** Show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^\infty_0 \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^n} dm$$ exists and find this limit.

**A)** (My attempt) Let $f_n = \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^n}$. Note that by binomial expansion $$(1+x^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} 1^{n-k} (x^2)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} x^{2k} = 1 + nx^2 + {{n}\choose{2}} x^4 + {{n}\choose{3}} x^6 + \ldots$$ So we have $f_n \to 0$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$. On the other hand, we have $$|f_n| = \bigg \vert \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^n} \bigg  \vert \leq 1 \in L^1((0,\infty),m).$$ Therefore by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we obtain $$\int^\infty_0 f_n dm \to \int^\infty_0 0 dm = 0.$$

I am not quite sure about my answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your arguments are incomplete. Also, it is not true that $1 \in L^{1}(0,\infty)$. Try to find a constant $C$ such that $f_n(x)\leq \frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ and use the fact that $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$  is integrable.

Comment: You should also notice that our bound is incorrect since ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which has order $n^2$, but with another constant.

Comment: Note your integrated doesn't depend on $m$

Comment: I realized my mistake. But I couldn't find the bound. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that $n\le 2(n-1)$ for $n\ge 2.$ Furthermore, $n\le 3(n-2)$ for $n\ge 3.$ The last inequality implies

$$n^2 \le 18[(n-1)(n-2)/2],\, n\ge 3.$$

It follows that

$$1+nx^2 + n^2x^4 \le 18(1+(n-1)x^2+[(n-1)(n-2)/2]x^4)$$

for all $x\ge 0$ and all $n\ge 3.$

Using the binomial formula, we see this implies

$$\frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}} \le \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{1+(n-1)x^2+[(n-1)(n-2)/2]x^4}\le 18$$

for all $x\ge 0$ and all $n\ge 3.$ Therefore

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^{n}} = \frac{1+nx^2 + n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \le \frac{18}{1+x^2}$$

for all $x\ge 0$ and all $n\ge 3.$ Since $\dfrac{18}{1+x^2}\in L^1,$ and the $f_n$ converge pointwise to $0$ on $(0,\infty),$ the DCT gives $\int_0^\infty f_n \to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(1+x^2\,)\dfrac{1+nx^2+n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^n}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\;\;x^2(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+1\,)\dfrac{x^4\left(\dfrac{1}{x^4}+\dfrac{n}{x^2}+{n^2}\right)}{ x^{2n}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+{1}\right)^n } = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \;\;\dfrac{x^6}{x^{2n}},$$
so for $n\geqslant 4$,  $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \;\;\dfrac{x^6}{x^{2n}}=0,$$
then $$\dfrac{1+nx^2+n^2x^4}{(1+x^2)^n} = o\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)$$
i.e:  $\exists \,M \geqslant 0$, for all $n \geqslant 4 ,$ $$|f_n(x)| \leqslant \dfrac{M}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why $x \to \infty$? Why the first two limits are same?

Comment: I have edited my answer. did you get it now?

Comment: Thanks again. Why $x^{2n}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+{1}\right) = (1+x^2)^n$?

Comment: welcome. I have edited my answer.

Comment: if $n=2$ then $x^2 + x^4 \neq (1+x^2)^2 = 1 + 2x^2 +x^4$.

Comment: One more thanks again :) $f_n \to 0$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$, right?

Comment: I only see $f_n(x)\le M_n/(1+x^2).$ I don't see how you get a uniform bound $M.$